# Learning Python: templates and webpages (error in powershell) [$ : The term '$' is not recognized]

Tags: python, powershell

i am learning Python (using the book "Head First: Python" 2nd ed.)

I am stuck on page 220, where the subject is rendering a template from flask into a webpage.
I created my 3 templates (called base, entry and results) and then went to powershell and typed:

```
py -3 vsearch4web.py
```

which returns (and looks fine to me):

```
* Serving Flask app "vsearch4web" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

the following instruction from the book is:

```
$ python3 vsearch4theweb.py
```

The answer from powershell is:

```
$ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ python3 vsearch4web.py
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What does this mean? i can't get to find any answer related to this issue online.
Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: `python3 vsearch4theweb.py` just try this without the `$`

Comment: @Ajay more likely `py -3 vsearch4theweb.py`

Comment: The `$` is the powershell prompt, not something you need to type in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to type the `$` into powershell. `$` is most widely used to communicate to the reader that the following text is a shell/terminal command (usually on Linux/MacOS).

The error is due to the fact that powershell searches for a command/executable called `$`, which of course it does not find.

You should use `py -3` like you did in the previous example:

```
py -3 vsearch4theweb.py
```

Comment: How could the book simply assume i already knew that :( Anyway, okay, but if i input the command as you suggested, how is it going to be different from the fist time i typed it in?

Comment: @Cicomameli the script name is different

Comment: python3 vsearch4theweb won't work (Python was not found), while py -3 starts the server succesfully. Now i am getting a jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '<'. Should i make another post about it? i can't see anything wrong in my templates

Comment: @Cicomameli, yes, you should create a new question